# Error creating bean with name : Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

**Web.xml File**

```
    <web-app>
      <display-name>Accounting Pro</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/views/pages/login/login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- Spring Security -->


    </web-app>
```

**Servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">


    <!-- <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" /> -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cerp" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver" />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />


    <bean id='viewResolvers'
        class='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver'>
        <property name='viewClass'
            value='org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView'>
        </property>
        <property name='prefix' value='/WEB-INF/views/pages/jsp'></property>
        <property name='suffix' value='.jsp'></property>
    </bean>
<!--    <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/"></mvc:resources> -->

    <mvc:annotation-driven />



</beans>
```

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
    @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.cerp.accounting.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.cerp.accounting.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cerp")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    /**
     * Configure TilesConfigurer.
     */
    @Bean
    public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer(){
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(new String[] {"/WEB-INF/views/**/tiles.xml"});
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    /**
     * Configure ViewResolvers to deliver preferred views.
     */
    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        TilesViewResolver viewResolver = new TilesViewResolver();
        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }

    /**
     * Configure ResourceHandlers to serve static resources like CSS/ Javascript etc...
     */

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Annotation/JavaConfig](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) remove your web.xml file.